# how to read ngrams from a file and then match them with tokens

Tags: python, python-3.x, n-gram

i want to read ngrams which are saved in a file. and then match each word of those ngrams with individual token in my corpus if it match with that then replace it with ngram.let say i have these bigrams:

```
painful punishment
worldly life
straight path
Last Day
great reward
severe punishment
clear evidence
```

what i want to do is to read first bigram and then split it and comapre its first word "painful" with my tokens in corpus where it match with the token move to the next token and match it with the next word of bigram if it is "punishment" then replace it with one token as "painful punsihment". i dont know how to do this. i want to convert this logic into code.if any one can help me i will be really very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, this is not a question for StackOverflow (sounds like a homework question). You can easily discern various methods to accomplish this via Google. I will however give you one solution as I need to warm up:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import traceback, sys, re

'''
Open the bigrams file and load into an array.
Assuming bigrams are cleaned (else, you can do this using method below).
'''
try:
    with open('bigrams.txt') as bigrams_file:
        bigrams = bigrams_file.read().splitlines()
except Exception:
    print('BIGRAMS LOAD ERROR: '+str(traceback.format_exc()))
    sys.exit(1)

test_input = 'There is clear good evidence a great reward is in store.'

'''
Clean input method.
'''
def clean_input(text_input):
    text_input = text_input.lower()
    text_input = text_input.strip(' \t\n\r')
    alpha_num_underscore_only = re.compile(r'([^\s\w_])+', re.UNICODE)
    text_input = alpha_num_underscore_only.sub(' ', text_input)
    text_input = re.sub(' +', ' ', text_input)
    return text_input.strip()

test_input_words = test_input.split()
test_input_clean = clean_input(test_input)
test_input_clean_words = test_input_clean.split()

'''
Loop through the test_input bigram by bigram.
If we match one, then increment the index to move onto the next bigram.
This is a quick implementation --- you can modify for efficiency, and higher-order n-grams.
'''
output_text = []
skip_index = 0
for i in range(len(test_input_clean_words)-1):
    if i >= skip_index:
        if ' '.join([test_input_clean_words[i], test_input_clean_words[i+1]]) in bigrams:
            print(test_input_clean_words[i], test_input_clean_words[i+1])
            skip_index = i+2
            output_text.append('TOKEN_'+'_'.join([test_input_words[i], test_input_words[i+1]]).upper())
        else:
            skip_index = i+1
            output_text.append(test_input_words[i])
output_text.append(test_input_words[len(test_input_clean_words)-1])

print(' '.join(output_text))
```

Input:

```
There is clear good evidence a great reward is in store.
```

Output:

```
There is clear good evidence a TOKEN_GREAT_REWARD is in store.
```

Comment: thank you so much for replying.in my file there are not just bigrams ,there are ngrams.bigrams ,trigrams and so on.i already cleaned my corpus. this is not a home work.actually i am not working with english language so it is difficult to implement some solutions.i tried  one solution which i was thinking.i calculated frequency of both ngrams and unigrams and then compared them but how to replace them in file that was difficult to understand